# How can I overwrite a word from an 2d array?

Tags: c

I have created a 2d array where a user can input words.
I need to create 2 functions:

- 1st function is called Add and an Admin can add a user and his data.
- 2nd function is called Delete and an Admin can remove a user by typing his username. If his username is found in the 2d array created in Add function then all of user's data should be replaced by zeros. The thing is that I cannot overwrite/replace the user's data to zero.

The 2d array:

```
char pin[50][7][100];
```

each row contains a single user and each column contains his info like name, surname etc.

Here is the delete function:

```
printf("Enter the username of the user you want to delete: \n");
scanf("%s",&key);

for(i=0;i<50;i++){
  for(j=5;j<6;j++){
if (strcmp(pin[i][j],key)==0){
    k=i;
    flag=1;
    break;

      }


    }}

if (flag==1){


    do{
    printf("Are you sure you want to delete this user?\t (Yes or No)\n");

    scanf("%s",&api);
    }while((strcmp(api,"Yes")!=0) && (strcmp(api,"No")!=0) );

    if (strcmp(api,"Yes")==0){

    /* Here I need to replace with 0s!*/

    }

    else if (strcmp(api,"No")==0) {

    goto dlt;
}
}   

else{
printf("Error!Username not found.Please try again. \n");
}
```

Comment: Perhaps sitting down and writing code might be a good start

Comment: I have actually but I can not add the code here.some kind of error.

Comment: Copy 'n' paste the code - otherwise it looks like you want somebody else to write the code for you

Comment: Perhaps bung that into the question

Comment: Format your code. It looks utterly messy.

Comment: My bad.Added the code.

Comment: Why are you using `goto`?

Comment: `for(j=5;j<6;j++)`?? And remove `&` from the `scanf`s you've shown.

Comment: I need to return to some other part of the code after the function is done.

Comment: for(j=5;j<6;j++)
Yes I only need to find the username and then delete all the user's data

Comment: Why a loop? Why not just remove `for(j=5;j<6;j++)` and use 5 instead of `j`?

Comment: I lost you there.Could you explain it further please?

Comment: Normally, I'd regard `pin` as a 3D array; it has 3 dimensions.  I suppose it is a 2D array of fixed length strings, where the notion of 'string' uses/absorbs/consumes the third dimension. Using `scanf("%s",&key);` is dubious; if you have `char key[50];`, then you should pass `key` and not `&key` (and you should specify `%49s` in the format).

Comment: The for loop will happen only once with j having the value of 5

Comment: `for(i=0;i<50;i++){
  for(j=5;j<6;j++){
if (strcmp(pin[i][j],key)==0){/* ... */

      }


    }}` --> `for(i=0;i<50;i++){
if (strcmp(pin[i][5], key) == 0){/* ... */}


    }`

Comment: it will check all 50 lines though,right?

Comment: Yes. It will do the same thing as your code.

Comment: ok got it.But this is not the issue I'm mostly concerded.

Comment: I need to replace the whole line if the username is found with zeros.

Comment: @Sterg - Please sort out the format/indentation of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that the column 5 contains the username, and you have found the user you want to delete at row k.
You can delete the data by using strcpy to replace all the data with 0s.

```
for (j = 0; j < 7; j++)
{
    strcpy(pin[k][j],"0");
}
```

Comment: it works but I have not been taught  strcpy.Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: for (j = 0; j < 7; j++)
{
    pin[k][j][0] = '0';
    pin[k][j][1] = '\0';
}

Comment: You want them to be 0s right? Then you can set the first character to be '0', then '\0' as the second character to end the string.

Comment: I have face one more problem if u can help me.
When I imput data for like 2 lines of the array and then come back to the program; if I try to use add function again the data will not be inserted in the 3rd line as it were supposed tobe but it will be insterted in the first line and so it goes on..So it will overwrite the data that I had inserted.

Comment: @Ed Heal what do you mean?

Comment: @slerg - You have not got around to formatting and indenting the code!

Comment: Then you need to pass in another variable to mark the position in the function, or use a global variable.